# SQLAlchemy automap classes to model.py file

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there any way to take the classes that are created by [SQLAlchemy's `automap`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html) (reflected from an existing database) and write these to a `models.py` file (for use with Flask and a different database)?

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
dir(Base.classes)
...
```

In Django, this is possible with the [`inspectdb` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models):

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Comment: There's https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen

Comment: Or you can use: https://github.com/ksindi/flask-sqlacodegen